# How does Twitter live update its blog posts?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, blogs, comet

We are creating a blog for our company from scratch, and we made it possible with comet in PHP and jQuery to make new blog posts able to be updated.

But then we realised, what if a user edited or deleted their own blog post, which was halfway down the page? How would we update that?

**Update:** Whoops, I just realised that Twitter DOES NOT remove a blog post instantly if it has been deleted. But still, it would be nice to have such a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) solution then you are probably following some sort of [publish-subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

From there you have a few ways of achieving what you are looking for. One solution would be to have a subscription in place for each blog post that is visible on the page. Your blog backend could then monitor if any changes were made to blog posts and if they were publish information to any of the subscribed listeners. The listeners will receive the published information and can update or delete the blog post accordingly.

I'm not sure what Comet solution you are using so if this were done using [Pusher](http://pusher.com) I'd probably do it as follows (hopefully you can convert the ideas to your own solution):

#### HTML

Have a unique identifier on the HTML markup for each blog post entry that identified the channel to subscribe to.

```
<article data-entry-id="blog-post-1">
   Some blog post content
</article>
<!-- more blog posts -->
```

#### JavaScript

Since you are using jQuery you can find all the blog posts on the page:

```
var blogPosts = jQuery( 'article[data-entry-id]' );
```

You make your connection to the server, in this case Pusher:

```
var pusher = new Pusher( 'app_key' );
```

Then subscribe to a channel for each blog entry:

```
var channels = {}; // lookup if required later
var channel;
blogPosts.each( function( i, el ) {
  el = jQuery( el );
  var blogId = el.attr( 'data-entry-id' );
  channel = pusher.subscribe( blogId );
  channel.bind( 'blog_entry_updated', handleUpdate );
  channel.bind( 'blog_entry_deleted', handleDelete );
  channels[ blogId ] = channel;
} );
```

Now that a channel has been subscribed to for each blog post you need to write the code to handle events (data updates) that occur on those channels:

- `handleUpdate` is called when a blog post is updated
- `handleDelete` is called when the blog post is deleted

We'll assume that the data you send for a `blog_entry_updated` will be in the format:

```
{
  blogEntryId: 'an_id', // an ID that matches the data-entry-id attribute value
  html: '<!-- some HTML -->` // the HTML for the updated blog post
}
```

The `handleUpdate` function could do something like:

```
function handleUpdate( data ) {
  var blogId = data.blogEntryId;
  var el = jQuery( 'article[data-entry-id=' + blogId + ']' );
  el.html( data.html );
}
```

You would probably also want to add some sort of effect to indicate the blog post has updated.

*Note: I wouldn't recommend sending through very large chunks of HTML if you can avoid it. If you can send through a delta (indicating the portion of the blog post that's changed) that may be better.*

The `handleDelete` would do something similar:

```
function handleDelete( data ) {
  var blogId = data.blogEntryId;
  var el = jQuery( 'article[data-entry-id=' + blogId + ']' );
  el.slideUp( function() {
    el.remove(); // slide out of view then remove the element
  } );
}
```

#### PHP

On the server you just need to publish the changes.

If it's an update then (using the [Pusher PHP library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server)) you would do something like:

```
require( '../lib/Pusher.php' );
require( 'config.php' ); // general config. In this case it includes the Pusher config

// some code that handles the update, updates the DB etc.
// The result of which means we have a $blogEntryId value
// and $html for the updated content

// this data structure is converted to JSON to be consumed on the client
$data = array( 'blogEntryId' => $blogEntryId, 'html' => $html );

$pusher = new Pusher( APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, APP_ID );

// trigger the event on the appropriate channel, using the update event
$pusher->trigger( $blogEntryId, 'blog_entry_updated', $data );
```

This will result in the `$data` being delivered to the client and the `handleUpdate` function being called.

The deleted functionality is very similar except we don't have any HTML to send:

```
$data = array( 'blogEntryId' => $blogEntryId );

$pusher = new Pusher( APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, APP_ID );

$pusher->trigger( $blogEntryId, 'blog_entry_deleted', $data );
```

As I mentioned above, hopefully you can apply something similar to this solution to your own Comet implementation.

Comment: May I ask, what's the `.subscribe()` option of Pusher equivalent to, so I can convert it? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: The subscribe is used to identify interest in a particular topic or item. In the case above it's used for each blog post. Under the hood we send our own `pusher:subscribe` message to our service which is translated and the client is marked as being interested in updates on that channel/topic/subject (blog post entry). See: http://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol#subscription-events